# powershell : output is only showing number of rows affected for a sql script

Tags: t-sql, powershell-2.0

I am running a very simple TSQL code in powershell. But the output only shows number of affected rows but not the actual results. Code is as follows:

```
function test([string] $Hostname )
{
    try
    {
    $con="server=$Hostname;database=master;Integrated security=sspi"
    $da=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ("                      
                 select * from sysdatabases 
                ",$con)
    $dt=New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $da.fill($dt)|Out-Null

    $da.fill($dt) | Format-table -AutoSize
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        ## Do something with the exception 
        write-host "Could not run test function for "+$Hostname
    }

}
foreach ($Hostname in Get-Content $ServerList)
{
    test($Hostname)
}
```

Any help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I'd write a simple .bat file that calls osql ;)  But I don't see where you iterate through any of the resultset (either $da, or $dt).  I suspect all that data is actually there: all you have to do is display it.

Comment: yes. i have written couple of scripts but never had this problem...please help

Comment: I never had to iterate through the results...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing the SQL Client tools and use SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 instead of having to create & manage everything via System.Data.SqlClient. Then your code will become:

```
function test([string] $Hostname )
{
    try {
        invoke-sqlcmd -server $hostname -database master -query "select * from sysdatabases" |ft -auto
    } catch [Exception] {
        ## Do something with the exception 
        write-host "Could not run test function for "+$Hostname
    }
}
```

[SqlDAtaAdapter.Fill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx) returns the *number of rows* that were filled, which is why you get what you're getting. If you want to continue this way, you'll need to iterate through the DataTable that you've filled, as paulsm4 points out.

Comment: Hi, when I use invoke-sqlcmd and try to format it as table then it says "The pipeline has been stopped." any idea?

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen that. Does it give any more detail? the exact exception may shed some light.